# JSTL Taglib uri for Tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, tomcat, jstl

Can anybody help me oput by letting me know the "taglib uri" for JSTL tags in TOMCAT 6.0

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"  prefix = "C"%>
doesnt seem to work its throwing an "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application" exception.......!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is the working URI, which is I am using..

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

You should add jstl.jar in your classpath..